# Запрос SQL (SQL SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Условная таблица:

| Discipline | Person |
| --- | --- |
| Matem | 101 |
| BD | 102 |
| OOP | 101 |
| OOP | 102 |
| BD | 103 |

Нужно написать SELECT, который возвращал бы список предметов, который бы не изучал пользователь 102. Т.е. должно вернуть Matem, BD

WHERE Person != 102 не работает потому что тогда возвращает еще и OOP. С HAVING тоже не получилось. Я еще совсем новичок

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *Нужно написать SELECT, который возвращал бы список предметов, который бы не изучал пользователь 102.* Вот именно это и надо запрашивать. А не список предметов которые изучал пользователь "не 102".

Comment: А что с having пробовали ? вам надо получить по каждому предмету количество записей с пользователем 102 (внутри sum можно писать case если что) и убедится что он 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Discipline
FROM myTable
WHERE Discipline NOT IN (SELECT Discipline FROM myTable WHERE Person = 102)
```

Comment: От души! вроде разобрался с этим NOT IN всё красиво (чики-пуки)